# Upload JAR into database

Tags: java, mongodb

Is it possible to upload jar as a file into database ? I need to upload jars into mongodb. I don't know how to do that. I know about file upload with Spring Boot.

I know it is possible to upload zip in database. But not finding information about JAR/WAR files.

Comment: Files are just sequences of bytes. It doesn't make a difference whether it's an image, a zip file or a jar file (which is a zip file as explained in the answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAR and WAR files are nothing more than a renamed ZIP file. If you want to see it yourself rename `something.jar` to `something.zip` and open it using archive manager.

Since you said you know how to upload a ZIP you should follow the same procedure. If the file is small (e.g. less than 4MB) perhaps using BSON is the best approach. See [Storing Large Objects and Files in MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/storing-large-objects-and-files-in-mongodb).

Comment: so you think same approach should be used ?

Comment: Yes. Each file can be persisted as bytes into any database. If the database doesn't support `byte` storage you can always encode it as `String`.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean saving a jar file into a database - it is depends on the database's support of [BLOB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object) data types.

And if you mean use Java language based stored procedures from JAR file - with [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/java.101/b12021/storproc.htm) and [PostgreSQL](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/10/introduction-to-postgresql-pljava.html) this is possible. MongoDB supports server side JavaScript stored procedures only.